# Доступ к классу из вызванного события [NodeJS]

Tags: node.js, классы, сокет

Подскажите, как сделать доступ к полю `this.OnlineId`
.`OnData` вызывается `Socket` при получении данных. Из этого метода мне нужно получить поля класса `Client`. Как это можно сделать?

```
module.exports = class Client  {
constructor(Socket) {

    this.Socket = Socket;
    this.OnlineId = 'cocbuilder.srv@yandex.ru';

    console.log(this.OnlineId); // cocbuilder.srv@yandex.ru

    this.Socket.on('data', this.OnData);
    this.Init();

}
OnData(Packet) {
    console.log(this.OnlineId); // undefined
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заменить `this.Socket.on('data', this.OnData);` на `this.Socket.on('data', (a) => this.OnData(a) );`